# Host file and localhost modification for subfolders on an ip address

Tags: localhost

I want to test site locally, but having problem in php include and required.

eg: localhost/site1/index.php
index.php is looking a file under localhost/abc.php to include, but file is in site1 folder.

I want that if I type site1 or site 2 in browser, WAMP server should load to localhost/site1 or site2

I have tried editing host file in drivers/etc folder

127.0.0.1/ localhost
127.0.0.1/site1 site1
127.0.0.1/site2 site2

but its not working.

I am using Windows 7
WAMP
apache2